# How to use a monitor (synchronized) in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I'm looking to create multiple asynchronous threads in Java and pass messages between them. I send data to a data structure in the destination node and they poll for it. But access to that data structure must be locked.

I use this line to create the lock:

> private final Object lock = new Object();

And this function to access the structure:

```
public int mailboxSize()
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {
        return mailbox.size();
    }
}
```

My concern is that if all the nodes use this class/cookie-cutter for their code, all locks will be the same and I will have only 1 lock instead of the n I'm hoping for. Is that true? If so, how can I create a unique lock for each node? Maybe some incrementing id? Does the lock have to be of type object or can I use int or Integer instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface and the classes that implement it.

Partway down on this link, the have some code showing how to setup a producers and a few multithreads consumers. Just what you want I thinks.

Comment: That's really close to perfect! The only issue with that data structure is that it makes it tough to access an arbitrary element. Maybe I should work around that though. Too bad there's no BlockingArrayList.